# Modificar el valor de la iteracion con un foreach en JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<c:set var="inicio" value="${4}"></c:set>
<c:set var="fin" value="${20}"></c:set>
<c:forEach var="j" begin="${inicio}" end="${fin}">                  
    <c:out vaue="${j}"></c:out>
    <c:if test="${j == 12}">
        <c:set var="inicio" value="${1}"></c:set>
    </c:if>     
</c:forEach>
```

No se si en este caso tenga algun error pero no me funciona correctamente. La idea es que muestre los numeros hasta el 12 empezando por el 4 y cuando llegue a 12 pues comenzar de 1 a 12 la proxima vez.
Lo que quiero mostrar es lo siguiente: 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,1,2,3,4,5......

Les agradecería su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `<c:out vaue="${j}"></c:out>`, debería ser `<c:out value="${j}"></c:out>` para imprimir el valor de `j`.

Además, para reiniciar el valor de `inicio` a **1** cuando `j` llega a **12**, debes reiniciar la variable `inicio` fuera del bucle `forEach`, en lugar de dentro del `if`. Es por esto que `inicio` solo se reinicia en el bucle actual y no en los siguientes bucles.

Puede que esto te sea de ayuda:

```
<c:set var="inicio" value="${4}"></c:set>
<c:set var="reinicios" value="${0}"></c:set>
<c:set var="fin" value="${20}"></c:set>
<c:set var="maxReinicios" value="${2}"></c:set> <!-- número máximo de reinicios -->
<c:forEach var="j" begin="${inicio}" end="${fin}">                  
    <c:out value="${j}"></c:out>
    <c:if test="${j == 12 and reinicios < maxReinicios}">
        <c:set var="inicio" value="${1}"></c:set>
        <c:set var="reinicios" value="${reinicios+1}"></c:set>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${reinicios == maxReinicios}">
        <c:set var="reinicios" value="${0}"></c:set>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: si te entiendo perfectamente, pero queria ver la posibilidad de reiniciar la variable inicio a 1 dentro del mismo ciclo para evitar hacer otros ciclos adicionales. Tengo que empezar en un mes específico que representa el número de inicio hasta 12 y luego desde 1 hasta 12 nuevamente

Comment: He editado la respuesta utilizando un sólo ciclo. Para esto he creado una nueva variable reinicios para introducir manualmente el número de reinicios en el bucle que se quieren hacer. No veo otra posiblidad.

Comment: lo intenté con una forma parecida a como lo planteaste pero el <c:set var="inicio" value="${1}"></c:set> no me pone el valor de la variable inicio en 1 para la próxima iteración del for y continua con el valor siguiente; continua en 13